# Core dumped, how to increase matrix dimension(usable), error in freeing 2d pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, complex-numbers, coredump

Here is one simple program. Objective is,

1. Remove core dumped error or somehow dealing with bigger dimension matrix. Although, I have used dynamic memory allocation.
2. In this program I have made one comment for freeing pointer, that gives an error if I don't make it comment. But as I know column should be free first than rows of pointer, that is not happening here, why is that so ?
3. If there is any way to optimize this code or suggestion or improvement or good habit for programming, you r welcome

Program is here,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>

        int main () 

        {
           int i,j,N=724; // core dumped start from 724 (least) on my laptop
           double complex var[N][N], **array;//, **var1, **var2,;

        // ALLOCATIONG 2D ARRAY
        array = malloc(N * sizeof *array + (N * (N * sizeof **array))); 

        // SOMETHING WITH "var" AND ASSIGN TO 2D POINTER "array"
        for ( i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        var[i][j] = (i+j)+((i+50)*j)*I;// SOMETHING WITH "var"
        printf("Value of var 1st time[%i,%i] = %f\t%f\n", i,j, var[i][j], cimag(var[i][j]));
        }
        } 
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        *(array+j)=&var[j][0];//ASSIGNING TO POINTER
        }

        printf("\n\n\n\n");
        for ( i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        printf("Value of array[%i,%i] = %f\t%0f\n", i,j, creal(*(*(array+i)+j)),cimag(*(*(array+i)+j)) );
        }
        }

        /* // BLOW LOOP FOR FREEING, GIVES ERROR
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
          free(array[i]);
        }
        */
        free(array); // THIS IS (MAY BE, I DON'T KNOW) FOR ONLY FREEING ROW POINTERS

         return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a large enough stack to hold 524176 array elements?

Comment: I don't know how to check stack memory.  But my memory(RAM) was free around 5.8 GB(out of ~8GB) while running.

Comment: The program stack won't be given all of that, it is allocated a specific amount, and not very much. The program stack does not dynamically grow from available resources. I don't understand why the code defines this large local array and then allocates memory to point to to its elements. Why not just allocate memory for the data itself?

Comment: Sorry But my (core) field is not computer science, So I might not be able to understand. But ultimately I want to things working so I asked.
Thanks for suggesting "Valgrind" like tool. I don't know about such tools.

Comment: Do you mean var[N][N] ? and than I assign its values to array, rather than directly ?
Actually I have done that, But N=724 is the limit even after that. So I thought there may be some other mistake, because the limit should go up.

Comment: You probably hit the limit of the stack size, since `var` is a local variable.

Comment: Oh, sorry I tried but it shows here core dumped.
See line, is it correct ?

*(*(array+i)+j)= (i+j)+((i+50)*j)*I;

Answer (score 1):

Reason of error is freeing memory which wasnt dynamically allocated.

Here

```
double ** array = malloc(X * sizeof(double *));
```

You have allocated space for `X` pointers to double but none space for any of these pointers.

For each pointer/row you have to allocate space separately, otherwise dereferencing them would lead to undefined behavior.

[Here is example how to work with array of pointers which you should apply on your usecase.](https://ideone.com/pcq7N4)

---

Also instead of this semantics

```
*(array+j)
```

You should use (for better readability)

```
array[j]
```

Comment: Thanks,Filip.
Is my method wrong for dynamically allocating ?
Is there any other way to free memory in the way I have defined ?
What about core dumped ?

Comment: Not my DV but the whole idea of `double ** array = malloc(N * sizeof *array + (N * (N * sizeof **array)));` is STRANGE.

Comment: Sure it is pretty STRANGE, but its OPs code. @STRANGE please take a look [HERE(click)](https://ideone.com/pcq7N4) so you hopefully understand how to allocate/free array of pointers.

Comment: The nice linked example shows the typical way to go, should that be in the answer?

Comment: Thanks for tip, i will add it to answer.

Comment: Sorry to be boring but the linked code is short enough to be included in the answer, since the proper answer is "don't do it that way".

Comment: No its fine. Its better to tell the mistakes instead of DV without explanation.

Comment: Iam glad it helped you, what i (and probably others) could recommend you is to create programs in smaller steps. Create a big program and then debug it is not he best way, even for not experienced person. Make small, but clear and correct steps :-) Its easier to understand and find bug.

Comment: I have created function to do that(same as in the link given by you,"ideone.com"), but it is not working.(shows core dumped) Can you give me function for doing this ?

Comment: @STRANGE Could you upload it on ideone as i did and send me link?

Comment: @STRANGE Check it here -- https://ideone.com/xuq0dG. I had to remove these complex things because i hadnt that library, but it compiles now so just add 'complex' and these functions and it should run well :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working well. But Why is it not printing "Deallocated array" ? Does that mean array is not de-allocated ?

Comment: Oh great YW, feel free to accept an answer. Because you are no calling function to deallocate array, you are freeing it in main. :-)